# Replace sections that have low volume with silence in Adobe Audition

Tags: adobe-audition, silence

I'm annoyed by certain sections of my long audio file that involve breathing and other mouth noises. I want to silence (not delete) these sections automatically. How can I do this?

So for example, sections like this (highlighted):
[image]

Ideally I can set the maximum volume a section is allowed to contain, and everything below that is silenced. Sort of like a reverse hard limiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Audition, but most DAWs come with  a noise gate. Use one with a filter to more accurately hone in on the right frequencies.

Alternatively, for something much 'smarter' you could use something like [Waves DeBreath](https://www.waves.com/plugins/debreath#removing-vocal-breaths-with-debreath), specifically designed for the task.

[image]